# Does B450 or X370 motherboards support Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, amd-ryzen

I want to buy new Asrock B450 Steel Legend and worry if it will support Windows 7 x64.
I check the web page and they have drivers for Windows 7 x64 but the retailer warning me about can have some issues in Windows 7.

I know that the Ryzen G series only run on Windows 10 but What about Ryzen 5 1600?

Answer (score 1):

my first answer from the top of my head would be "Yes" because of common sense but I wanted to check just to be sure before answering your questions.

I have found a few debates about Asrock B450 motherboard. It is possible to run Windows 7 but you will have a lot of problems since Windows 7 doesn't have any USB 3.0 drivers, and the Asrock B450 has nothing but USB 3.0 ports (even any USB 2.0 ports are driven through the USB 3.0 controller).

Comment: All the problems are because the USB drivers? If that I can buy an X370 Killer SLI, that have two PS/2 connectors. Also I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=145&v=lQq7YvfIujc

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Well, technically probably yes, but you will be locked out of Windows Update, making this a very dangerous endeavor.

As per [Windows 7 requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements):

> Up through the following AMD 6th Generation Processors (A-Series Ax-8xxx & E-Series Ex-8xxx & FX-870K)

Ryzen is only supported starting from Windows 10 1703.

Microsoft has decided to block access to Windows Update on “unsupported” CPUs:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012982/the-processor-is-not-supported-together-with-the-windows-version-that

> This error occurs because new processor generations require the latest Windows version for support. For example, Windows 10 is the only Windows version that is supported on the following processor generations:
>
> - Intel seventh (7th)-generation processors
> - AMD “Bristol Ridge”
> - Qualcomm “8996"
>
> Because of how this support policy is implemented, devices that run the following Windows versions and that have a seventh generation or later generation processor may no longer be able to scan or download updates through Windows Update or Microsoft Update:
>
> - Windows Server 2012 R2
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows 7

Comment: Well, finally it works, it was a pain to install Windows and the drivers only with the keyboard but I'm here writing this from Windows 7 x64 running on a Ryzen 5 1600.